# Selectively loading backrefs in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Following the examples here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html, one can easily load *all* the addresses for the `User` with name Jack like so:

```
jack = session.query(User).options(joinedload('addresses')).\
       filter_by(name='jack').all()
```

However, there is no example for how to load only those addresses that match a certain criterion - let's say I only want those addresses from Jack that end with '@google.com'.

Is this possible with SQLAlchemy - specifically, can I pass something to `joinedload()` or `subqueryload()` that allows me to filter addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a join manually then specify `contains_eager`, like this:

```
session.query(User).join(User.addresses) \
                   .filter(User.name == "jack",
                           Address.email.like("%@google.com")) \
                   .options(contains_eager(User.addresses))
```

This is outline in the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result).

Comment: Thanks! The docs do contain this, but man is it easy to miss!